# Customize 3d plots in Julia

Tags: plot, julia, surface

I am currently using Plots (GR) for 3D plots in Julia.
However, I have found some issues and no solutions so far.

1. Is there any way to include annotations on a 3D plot?
2. How can I rotate the `zlabel`? on GR, `zguidefontrotation` isn't working.
3. 3d plots are generated with vasts white areas around the main figure, you can notice this even in the documentation (for the [Lorenz attractor](https://docs.juliaplots.org/stable/)). I have tried using margins but still looks odd. Is there any similar layout_tight in Julia?
4. As an alternative for the annotation I am trying to include the information in the title; however, it still again is shown far from the figure. I tried again with the margin options but I couldn't make it work nicely.

This is my short example:

```
using Plots; gr()
using Plots.PlotMeasures
using LaTeXStrings

te = 1e-6*rand(2000)
xe = rand(2000)
ye = rand(2000)
ze = rand(2000)


B = round(1e6*te[1000]; digits=3)
p = plot([xe[1:1000]],[ye[1:1000]],[ze[1:1000]],
    fontfamily = "Computer Modern",
    camera = (45,15),
    margin = -15mm,
    top_margin= -25mm,
    title = L"t = %$B \, \textrm{\mu T}",
    titlefontsize= 12,
    xaxis=(L"x",(-1.2,1.2)), 
    yaxis=(L"y",(-1.2,1.2)), 
    zaxis=(L"z",(-1.2,1.2)), 
    tickfontsize=6,
    guidefontsize=10,
    linewidth = range(0, 1, length = 1000),
    seriesalpha = range(0, 1, length = 1000),
    aspect_ratio=:equal,
    zguidefontrotation=-45,
    framestyle=:box,
    legend=false,
    dpi=300,)
```

[image: So far I have this figure]

Any suggestions within GR?

Comment: This is a really annoying limitation of GR. I'm not sure if the problem is with GR or Plots.jl but I have encountered all of these! Some dumb hacks that I've done in the past (to varying degrees of success):

1. Create an empty 2D plot, and use this as an "annotation" by doing a custom layout (I think you can also do this as an inset?) -- white space issues can sometimes be tricky here still.

2. If you don't need the legend, move the legend around and use that as your annotations... (can just use the legendtitle attribute for example)